Screen Sharing Not Working
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and an Nvidia 1050 graphics card. When I first installed Ubuntu on my computer, I noticed that I couldn't share the screen and that there was no option for it. I installed the Nvidia driver and started screen sharing, but now I'm experiencing occasional screen tearing and brief freezes in certain parts of the screen when scrolling up and down (this happens on the shared screen, not on the internal screen). How can I resolve these freezes and screen tearing issues?

How are you sharing the screen? Which app are you using? Edit your question and add these information.

I think this issue is mainly because Ubuntu by default uses Wayland.
Do:
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
if the output says "wayland", then go to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf. In the beginning of that file somewhere, you should see the line "#WaylandEnable=false"
Uncommment that line and hit save and reboot you system.
Once rebooted do:
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
it should output "x11"
Screen sharing should work after this.

Thank you for your answer.  The problem seems to be solved for now
